Autodesk Platform Services - ACC - Get Roles IDs
I am using the ACC API to add users to a project, when doing so in order to add roles to the users I need the role ID, however I can't find a good way to get the possible role IDs, there is no method in documentation that return the possible role IDs and they are not visible to the ACC user.
Writing the bad ways I find, but I am hoping there is a better way:
There is a method for this purpose in BIM360 API - https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-industry_roles-GET/
And right now it works for ACC projects as well, however documentation says it should not so I am worried about using it as a long term solution
I can manually add all roles to a specific folder and then get the roles using https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/document-management-projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-permissions-GET/

I wish to recommend use the Autodesk data Connector: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/data-connector/ to retrieve the roleIds. Set attribute: "serviceGroups": ["admin"]. The resulting extract will have all the roles in the account/project
